# How to terminate long running query in AWS Aurora postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have a process that loads csv files to AWS Aurora Postgres instance.

Some of the queries are stuck for some reason for more than an hour.
I tried to kill those queries using `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid>)` and `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid>)` but both failed.

I found out that RDS has specific super user role and tried - `grant rds_superuser to myuser;`
but still not working.

any ideas?

Thanks